# Is the moq project dead? Is it wise for me to invest in learning it?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, mocking, moq

I am fairly new to mocking frameworks and was trying to decide which one will be a good bet to start working on. I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242/rhino-mocks-typemock-moq-or-nmock-which-one-do-you-use-and-why) about the best mocking framework, and I can see a lot of people preferring moq, but when i saw the moq project's [change list](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/list), i can see that it has not been updated for almost an year now.
Is moq project dead? if yes, which will be a good mocking framework to start with today?

Comment: Investing in learning is always wise. Besides, it's only dead until you start maintaining it. Leverage FOSS

Comment: @sehe In theory, yes, I agree with you. But I was looking for a more pragmatic answer.

Comment: The codeplex page does not exist, and I still experience bugs in Moq from time to time. There has not been an update to Moq in more than a year, so I was wondering of you have any update on this since the tagged answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Moq is not dead, it's heavily used and it has a steady download count both via nuget and google code. It's just that it works so great that there hasn't been any show-stopper issues that require urgent fixes :P.

vNext is coming along (a lot of spiking, throwing away ideas, etc.) slowly, and its new home will be in http://moq.codeplex.com eventually.

NuGet has somewhat changed the dynamic here, 'cause it's now much less friction to release new bits more often. We'll catch-up with more frequent releases soon. I'm just terribly busy with other stuff (opensource too some of it, heard of netfx.codeplex.com?).

Yes, Microsoft uses it a lot, as well as many others.

Comment: +1 nice to have a definitive answer from the horse's mouth, as it were (I hope that phrase is universally understood)!

Comment: That link to codeplex has this message "This project is not yet published" and there is no way to get to the project for d/l

Comment: Even worse, currently the pageisnotfound.

Comment: Moq4 has moved to https://github.com/Moq/moq4 and has 13 commits so far this year, so: plenty active enough.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Statistics of usage](http://osherove.com/blog/2010/9/10/2010-poll-which-isolation-framework-do-you-use-in-net.html)
2. [Comparison of mocking frameworks](http://code.google.com/p/mocking-frameworks-compare/)

Comment: +1 The comparison link looks interesting in helping to make the decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list) it seems that the latest download was added on 12 April and the change version (`4.0.10827.Final`) is not consistent with the version from the list (`4.0.10818`).

However, it doesn't look like it's still being developed. Maybe the current release is deemed to be finished (hence the word Final).

This link for [Microsoft Unity 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17866) seems to suggest that you need Moq 4.0, which is quite encouraging!

Comment: It is the same version released in Aug 2010, [just marked as final](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount)

Comment: So, is it dead or just finished?

Comment: So maybe it's not under active development, but is deemed finished? Microsoft seem to like it.