# Moq: Dead or alive?

Tags: exception, moq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the moq project dead? Is it wise for me to invest in learning it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454936/is-the-moq-project-dead-is-it-wise-for-me-to-invest-in-learning-it)

This thread is a spin-off from the tread [Is the moq project dead or alive?....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454936/is-the-moq-project-dead-is-it-wise-for-me-to-invest-in-learning-it), and since the answer is outdated and refers to a CodePlex site that doesn't exist, I'd like to reopen the issue.

I've been using Moq for quite a while, and have mostly been satisfied. The problem is that from it's home at google code, it hasn't been updated since April 2011, which is starting to be a while.

Now that .NET 4.5 is here, I would expect some changes are needed. I also experience random bugs that I'm curious if they will be resolved at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-edit you had already found your answer:

https://github.com/Moq

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I just thought someone who had grabbed the source from google code and fixed some issues they had. And the former home at google code doesn't have any clear reference to github.